# Print on the same line

Tags: python

A little backstory: I'm making a multitool for a bigger program but ran into an issue that I really can't get my head around. It's just print statements that are used for showing the user all the avalible options. I apologise if there's any wrong grammar or if I've misspelled some words, if something is unreadable feel free to let me know and I can explain what I meant.

Problem: I want them to get printed on the same row under the credline_mid. Pic 1 = How it prints it Pic 2 = a recreation made in paint that shows how I want to have it. Any help that could be given would be much appreciated.
[[Pic 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WvQKZ.png)]
[[Pic 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Kw98S.png)]

Code:

```
def logo_mid():
    print(Fore.MAGENTA + r"""____/\\\_______/\\\_____________________________/\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\_________________________________/\\\\\\______        
 ___\///\\\___/\\\/_____________________________\///////\\\/////_________________________________\////\\\______       
  _____\///\\\\\\/_____________________________________\/\\\_________________________________________\/\\\______      
   _______\//\\\\___________________/\\\\\\\\\\\________\/\\\____________/\\\\\_________/\\\\\________\/\\\______     
    ________\/\\\\__________________\///////////_________\/\\\__________/\\\///\\\_____/\\\///\\\______\/\\\______    
     ________/\\\\\\______________________________________\/\\\_________/\\\__\//\\\___/\\\__\//\\\_____\/\\\______   
      ______/\\\////\\\____________________________________\/\\\________\//\\\__/\\\___\//\\\__/\\\______\/\\\______  
       ____/\\\/___\///\\\__________________________________\/\\\_________\///\\\\\/_____\///\\\\\/_____/\\\\\\\\\___ 
        ___\///_______\///___________________________________\///____________\/////_________\/////______\/////////____""")


def credline_mid():
    print("""
_____________________________________________Made by [EN/SWE] PewPew#4450______________________________________________""")


def fav_options():
    print("""
╔═══════════════╗
║   Favorites   ║
╠══╦════════════╣
│1 │Inject      │
│2 │Reinstall   │
│3 │Quit X-Tool │
└──┴────────────┘""", end='')
def installer_options():
    print("""
╔══════════════════╗
║  File installer  ║
╠══╦═══════════════╣
│4 │Visuals        │
│5 │Translations   │
│6 │ASI plugins    │
│7 │LUA scripts    │
│8 │UI configs     │
│9 │XML maps       │
│10│Vehicles       │
│11│Outfits        │
│12│Headers        │
└──┴───────────────┘""", end='')
def delete_options():
    print("""
╔══════════════════╗
║  Delete Options  ║
╠══╦═══════════════╣
│13│Translations   │
│14│Hotkeys        │
│15│Saved options  │
│16│Headers        │
│17│ASI Files      │
│18│LUA Scripts    │
│19│Reinstall      │
└──┴───────────────┘""", end='')
def social_options():
    print("""
╔══════════════════╗
║   Social Links   ║
╠══════════════════╣
│  X-Force Socials │
├──┬───────────────┤
│20│Youtube Channel│
│21│Discord Server │
│22│Dashboard      │
│23│Forum          │
├──┴───────────────┤
│  My Own Socials  │
├──┬───────────────┤
│24│Shop           │
│25│Youtube Channel│
│26│Discord Server │
└──┴───────────────┘""", end='')
def misc_options():
    print("""
╔══════════════════╗
║       Misc       ║
╠══╦═══════════════╣
│27│X-Tool Tutorial│
│28│Credits        │
│29│X-Tool Support │
│30│Update checker │
│31│Changelog      │
│32│Dev-Mode       │
│33│Quit X-Tool    │
│34│Inject         │
└──┴───────────────┘""", end='')
def settings_options():
    print("""
╔════════════════════╗
║      Settings      ║
╠══╦═════════════════╣
│35│UI-Editor        │
│36│Sound Editor     │
│37│Favorites Editor │
│38│Reset X-Tool     │
│39│Hotkeys          │     
└──┴─────────────────┘""", end='')



logo_mid()
credline_mid()
fav_options()
installer_options()
delete_options()
social_options()
misc_options()
settings_options()
```

I've tried putting end='' on the end of the print statement but didnt work.

Then I looked for some stack overflow threads that fit my problem, unfortunately I didn't find anything.

Lastly I tried using our beloved friend chatgpt but unfortunately no help there.

Comment: After each "right edge" of the box, you've explicitly typed a new-line, so unfortunately, this won't work. If you really want to make a tool like this, people often use [curses](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/curses.html) for CLI menus

Comment: There's no easy way to do what you want.  You'd have to print the top row of each menu side by side, then the second row of each menu side by side, and so on.

Comment: put each line into a list than loop through all of them with `end=''`

Comment: I understand what you mean with "If you really want to make a tool like this, people often use curses for CLI menus" But the "multitool" is controlled either thrue voice controll, inputing a number or using [Pickle](https://pypi.org/project/pick/) . I don't what you mean with the "right edge" thingy

Comment: Ohh god no is there really no way to print it like that... Well better get to work then,

Comment: Do you think you could give me a little example would really help me understand on how to do that

Comment: By "right edge" , I mean the vertical bars on the menus. You've typed a new-line as part of the string literal, so that's what will be printed... Therefore, not possible to do side-by-side, as written.

Answer (score 0):

First, seprate menus into just strings

```
fav_options = """╔═══════════════╗
║   Favorites   ║
╠══╦════════════╣
│1 │Inject      │
│2 │Reinstall   │
│3 │Quit X-Tool │
└──┴────────────┘""";

installer_options = """╔══════════════════╗
║  File installer  ║
╠══╦═══════════════╣
│4 │Visuals        │
│5 │Translations   │
│6 │ASI plugins    │
│7 │LUA scripts    │
│8 │UI configs     │
│9 │XML maps       │
│10│Vehicles       │
│11│Outfits        │
│12│Headers        │
└──┴───────────────┘""";
```

Then make a list of them , and place them in a 2D array

```
menus = [fav_options, installer_options]
full_menu = [m.splitlines() for m in menus]
```

And iterate each line, replacing None (returned from `zip_longest` when the zip is out of range) with the width of the column.

```
from itertools import zip_longest

for row in zip_longest(*full_menu):
    line = []
    for i, menu in enumerate(row):
        if menu == None:
            line.append(' ' * len(full_menu[i][0])) # get width of menu header
        else:
            line.append(menu)
    print(' '.join(line))
```

Example output

```
╔═══════════════╗ ╔══════════════════╗
║   Favorites   ║ ║  File installer  ║
╠══╦════════════╣ ╠══╦═══════════════╣
│1 │Inject      │ │4 │Visuals        │
│2 │Reinstall   │ │5 │Translations   │
│3 │Quit X-Tool │ │6 │ASI plugins    │
└──┴────────────┘ │7 │LUA scripts    │
                  │8 │UI configs     │
                  │9 │XML maps       │
                  │10│Vehicles       │
                  │11│Outfits        │
                  │12│Headers        │
                  └──┴───────────────┘
```

> the "multitool" is controlled either thrue voice controll, inputing a number

You could run an REST API, or other RPC server and still send requests to that via voice... You ideally would not use `input()` for that.

Comment: This is so helpfull thank you so much will look into the RPC server. When I said "inputing a number" I meant like the user can choose if he/her wants to navigate by typing a number or voice and yeah stuff like that you know but once again ty so much for that good example and for the good tip with the RPC

Comment: Can't seem to find that is it at the top?